# Detect Multiple Touch

Tags: lua, coronasdk

In my game, I control an object using touch event. When I touch the right half of the screen, the object rotates, when I touch the left half of the screen, the object moves.  It works perfectly when it's a single touch, but when I touch any side of the screen and then start touching the other side at the same time,  it results in an unexpected, mixed-up behavior.

I guess my question is, how to separate or differentiate multiple touches one from the other.

```
 system.activate( "multitouch" )

    onTouch = function (event)

    if (event.phase == "began") then
        pX = event.x       -- Get start X position of the touch
        print( "ID:"..tostring(event.id) )
        if (event.x > centerX) then     --if the touch is in the right or left half of the screen
            xPos = "right"
        else 
            xPos = "left"
        end

    elseif (event.phase == "moved") then
        local dX = (event.x - pX ) 
        if (xPos == "right") then
           rotatePlayer(dx)
        else 
            movePlayer(dX)
    end
```

Update:

```
system.activate( "multitouch" )

local touchID = {}         --Table to hold touches

onTouch = function (event)

    if (event.phase == "began") then

        print( "ID:"..tostring(event.id) )
        if (event.x > centerX) then     --if the touch is in the right or left half of the screen
            touchID[event.id] = {}
            touchID[event.id].x = event.x 
            xPos = "right"
            pX = touchID[event.id].x      -- Get start X position of the touch
        else 
            touchID[event.id] = {}
            touchID[event.id].x = event.x 
            xPos = "left"
            pX = touchID[event.id].x
        end

    elseif (event.phase == "moved") then
        print( "ID:"..tostring(event.id) )

        local dX  
        if (xPos == "right") then
           touchID[event.id].x = event.x 
           dX = touchID[event.id].x - pX
           rotatePlayer(dx)
        else 
           touchID[event.id].x = event.x 
           dX = touchID[event.id].x - pX
           movePlayer(dX)
    end
```

Same problem still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you're ignoring `event.id` field, that's why you have multiple touches behavior mixed up.

Track each new touch by storing it in some list when you get `began` phase. Include touch initial coords (your `pX` goes there) and anything else you might need later. When you get other events (moved/ended/cancelled), you should check the list of active touches, find actual touch by `event.id` and perform logic for that exact touch.

Comment: I tried adding the touch IDs to a table and get them in touch moved, but the same problem still exists. Please check my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

You're still mixing touches data. `xPos` is a touch' function, so it must be stored in touch events, and not in global variable that gets updated with data from another touches.

Also, move duplicated lines out of `if` branches, they're identical. Code will become simpler and much easier to read and comprehend.

```
system.activate( "multitouch" )

local touchID = {}         --Table to hold touches

onTouch = function (event)
    local x, id, phase = event.x, event.id, event.phase
    print( "ID:"..tostring(id) )

    if (phase == "began") then
        touchID[id] = {
            x = x,
            logic = (x > centerX) and rotatePlayer or movePlayer
        }
    elseif (phase == "moved") then
        local touch = touchID[id]
        touch.logic(x - touch.x)
    end
end
```

Note that you still should remove touches on "ended/cancelled" phase.

Edit: there might be multiple touches on the same side of screen, so either ignore new touches, or average them somehow.